# Too many Email Invocations: 11

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

I am deactivating no of users and when user is deactivated then all of the open opportunities of user has been assigned to their Manager.

But I am getting below error message:
Error Message:

> Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: / Source
>   organization:  (null) Failed to invoke future method 'public static
>   void changeOwner(List)' on class 'ChangeOpportunityOwner' for job
>   id ''
>
> caused by: System.LimitException: Too many Email Invocations: 11

Below is the Apex Code:

```
public without sharing class ChangeOpportunityOwner {       
  @Future
  public static void changeOwner(List<Id> usrIds){
    Boolean isUpdate=false;
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    Map<Id, Boolean> mapUserToActive = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
    try{
       for (User u1 : [SELECT Id, isActive FROM User]) { 
         mapUserToActive.put(u1.Id, u1.isActive);
       }
       List <user>usrs= [Select Id,Name,ManagerId,IsActive from user where Id=:usrIds];
       List<Opportunity> finalOptList=new List<Opportunity>();
       for(User u:usrs){   
         List<Opportunity>optys=[Select Id,OwnerId,StageName from Opportunity where OwnerId=:u.Id]; 
         for(Opportunity opt:optys){
           if(opt.StageName!='Closed Won' && opt.StageName!='Closed Lost')
           {
              if (mapUserToActive.get(u.ManagerId)== true &&                 mapUserToActive.get(u.ManagerId)!=null) {
                 opt.OwnerId=u.ManagerId;
              }
              else{ 
                  User usr= [Select Id,Name,ManagerId from user where Name='Manager’];
                  opt.OwnerId=usr.Id;
               }
      finalOptList.add(opt);
    // Set list of people who should get the email
      List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
      sendTo.add(u.ManagerId);
      mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
    //  Set who the email is sent from
      mail.setReplyTo('flow@test.com');
      mail.setSenderDisplayName('Support');
     // Set email contents - you can use variables!
      mail.setSubject('Open Opportunities transferred to you');
      String body = 'Dear Manager,<br> ';
      body +='<br>';
      body += 'Please note that '+u.name+'  has been deactivated as a Salesforce User hence all of its <br> Open Opportunities has been assigned to you if any.<br>';
      body +='<br>';
      body +='Kind regards,<br>';
      body +='<br>';
      body +='SFDC Support';
      mail.setHtmlBody(body);
isUpdate=true;
}
}
if(isUpdate)
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{mail},false);
}
if(isUpdate)
{
update finalOptList;
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
system.debug('An Exception Occured: '+e.getMessage());
}
}


@InvocableMethod(label='Change Opportunity Owner' description='It Change the owner of opportunity when owner is inactive')
public static void changeOwnerFuture(List<Id> usrIds)
{
changeOwner(usrIds);
}
}
```

Can somebody please help me what is wrong in apex code?
The opportunity reassignment email that I am sending via apex,it crossed the limit...

Below updated code fix the Too many email invocation error but when I deactivate multiple users and when manager receives an email,it displays only first user information.
Lets say I am deactivating 3 users A,B,C has same manager and when manager receives an email,total 3 mails received but in all emails  it displays User A's information.
Updated Code:

```
public without sharing class ChangeOpportunityOwner {       
@Future
public static void changeOwner(Id[] usrIds){
boolean isUpdate=false;
boolean isUpdate1=false;
boolean isUpdate2=false;
Id genericManagerId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Dhananjay Patil'].Id;
String genericName=[Select Id,Name from User where Id=:genericManagerId].Name;
Map<Id,User> usrMap=new Map<Id,User>([Select Id,Name,Manager.Name from User where Id=:usrIds]);
Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Owner.Name,Owner.Manager.Name,Owner.ManagerId,Owner.Manager.IsActive FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId =:usrIds AND IsClosed = FALSE];
Set<Id> managerIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Opportunity opp: opps) {
if(opp.Owner.ManagerId != null && opp.Owner.Manager.IsActive) {
opp.OwnerId = opp.Owner.ManagerId;
managerIds.add(opp.OwnerId);
isUpdate=true;
} else {
opp.OwnerId = genericManagerId;
managerIds.add(opp.OwnerId);
isUpdate1=true;
}

}

Messaging.Email[] messages = new Messaging.Email[0];
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Id templateId=[Select Id,DeveloperName,body,HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=:'Assign_Opportunities_to_New_Owner'].Id;
EmailTemplate templ=[Select Id,HtmlValue,body from EmailTemplate where Id=:templateId];
OrgWideEmailAddress owa=[Select Id,Address,DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address='test@test.com'];

for(User u1:usrMap.values()){ 
message.setSubject('Open Opportunities transferred to you');
message.setTargetObjectId(u1.managerId);
message.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owa.Id);
message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
message.setTemplateId(templateId);
//Setting PlainText Body
string test = '';
test=templ.body.replace('{!Opportunity.OwnerFullName}',u1.Name);
message.setPlainTextBody(test);
messages.add(message);
isUpdate2=true;
// } 
}
If((isUpdate||isUpdate1)&&isUpdate2){
Messaging.sendEmail(messages, false);
Database.update(opps, false);
}
}
@InvocableMethod(label='Change Opportunity Owner' description='It Changes the owner of opportunity when owner is inactive')
public static void changeOwnerFuture(Id[] usrIds)
{
changeOwner(usrIds);
}
}
```

Comment: First of all you need to remove the `SOQL` statement from the `for loop`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only call Messaging.sendEmail 10 times per transaction, but you can put many Messaging.Email items in a list.

```
Messaging.Email[] messages = new Messaging.Email[0];
for(...) {
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  // Set mail parameters
  messages.add(mail);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```

---

Realistically, you've massively over-engineered your code. Here's how I would optimize your code:

```
@future public static void changeOwners(Id[] userIds) {
  Id genericManagerId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Manager'].Id;
  Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Owner.ManagerId, Owner.Manager.IsActive FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId = :userIds AND IsClosed = FALSE];
  Set<Id> managerIds = new Set<Id>();
  for(Opportunity opp: opps) {
    if(opp.Owner.ManagerId != null && opp.Owner.Manager.IsActive) {
      opp.OwnerId = opp.Owner.ManagerId;
      managerIds.add(opp.OwnerId);
    } else {
      opp.OwnerId = genericManagerId;
    }
  }
  Messaging.Email[] messages = new Messaging.Email[0];
  for(Id managerId: managerIds) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    message.setSubject('You have new opportunities.');
    message.setTargetObjectId(managerId);
    message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    message.setPlainTextBody('You have new opportunities, etc, etc.');
    messages.add(message);
  }
  Messaging.sendEmail(messages, false);
  Database.update(opps, false);
}
```

Comment: If 1 user has more than 1 opportunities then I have to send only one notification email to thir manager. Messaging.sendEmail(messages); that u suggested,will it work in this case?

Comment: @DhananjayPatil You do have other problems with your code; you'll probably want something like a `Map<Id, User[]>` so you can keep track of all users deactivated by ManagerId, at which point you can add one email per manager.

Comment: If you can see when Opportunity for loop ends,I am sending an email to the manager. if(isUpdate)
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{mail},false);   If users are multiple then it sends no of notification email to the manager.

Comment: My Requirement is I have to deactivate list of users who is idle for More than 40 days.I take out the list of users from Report Tab and with the help of data loader I deactivated the user.When User Deactivate,it calls process builder which send first email alert notification to the inactive user and their manager email address.Then it calls my apex class method inwhich all  open opportunities assigned to the manager and sends an Opportunity Assignment notification to the manager via apex.Means As Manager I receive 2 notifications 1 is user deactivation by email alerts service and then opt..

Comment: @DhananjayPatil Basically, query the opportunities, loop over them to build a map based on manager Id, and then loop over the map's contents to build the emails. You might want to read more on [bulkification](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code).

Comment: @DhananjayPatil I added some more info to my answer that demonstrates how to use the loop I mentioned.

Comment: Based on ur latest code,How do i get the previous owner name of opportunity if i define =body like this:        body += 'Please note that '+opp.Owner.Name'   has been deactivated as a Salesforce User hence all of its <br> Open Opportunities has been assigned to you if any.<br>';

Comment: @DhananjayPatil You can use a `Map<Id, User[]>`, as I said before. The sample I wrote was illustrative, not literal. You should note that using this design, more than one user might be listed, so you may need to account for that as well. All you need to do is add Owner.Name to the opportunity query to get the old user's information.

Comment: I have used like this  String Nme=[Select Id,Name from User where Id=:usrIds].Name;
  List<User> u=[Select Id,Name from User where Name=:Nme];   then I am adding for loop before manageriD for loop like this :  for(User u1:u){ 
  for(Id managerId: managerIds) {} and I am ending the user for loop before  Messaging.sendEmail..Is this acceptable?

Comment: I have updated the code.Can you please check above 'Updated Code Section'.I am now getting inactive user name to the body of HTML template.Apologies but I am abegineer in salesforce and also not aware of to use map in certain situation.

Comment: Thank You So much for providing Optimize code.It works now.                    One I want to ask you here.When I receive an email,it always go to spam folder.What could be the reason behind this.I checked my Org Setting,it is proper.Is this because of I am using Email Body Inside Apex Class? You can check the updated code section above.I have edited the content.

Comment: Please find the updated code.I am facing an issue when I deactivate multiple users,As a manager when I receive Opportunity Reassignment email,it displays only first user's name information in all email templates.I have provided the details in updated code section.Can you please look into this?

Comment: @DhananjayPatil You shouldn't continually ask questions in comments, as they tend to get lost; I didn't even realize you'd asked about a spam email folder issue. Each unique problem should be a unique question, so that we, the community, can help you in the best way possible. Also, remember to try searching here on SFSE before you just ask, as the answers might already be out there. If an answer resolves the topic of the question, please mark it was resolved, and then ask a new question. You can ask as many questions as you'd like.

Comment: @DhananjayPatil That said, using a Map instead of a Set would help you organize the users into a list per manager. There's a number of ways you can do it. I'd probably start with a `Map<Id, Set<String>>`, where the key is the manager's ID, and the Set<String> is the list of user names.

Comment: The only issue I am facing here is the template for which I have replaced the body is only getting updated once.Resulting in duplicate content mail send for all users as opposed to unique email address for each users. 
Apologies for inconvenience. I will surely raised new questions next time as the the code that I had posted earlier worked fine when I receive an email for multiple users with correct user name.

Comment: I have asked another question for this.Maybe u can look into this.
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154879/single-email-message-bulckification-not-working-in-apex

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the soql and sendemail method within the for loop.I have refined your code as below.Redefine the logic as you need

Also what are you doing here?

```
for (User u1 : [SELECT Id, isActive FROM User]) { 
            mapUserToActive.put(u1.Id, u1.isActive);
        }
```

it will fetch all the users in the org . filter the users based on the condition

```
public without sharing class ChangeOpportunityOwner {       
@Future
public static void changeOwner(List<Id> usrIds){
    Boolean isUpdate=false;
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    Map<Id, Boolean> mapUserToActive = new Map<Id, Boolean>();


         User usr= [Select Id,Name,ManagerId from user where Name='Manager'];


        Map <id,user> usrMap = new Map<id,user>();
        set<id> mgrIds=new set<id>();
         for(User u:[Select Id,Name,ManagerId,IsActive from user where Id=:usrIds])
         {
             usrmap.put(u.id,u);
             mgrIds.add(u.managerid);

         }
         Map<id,user> managerUsrMap = new Map<id,user>([Select Id,Name,ManagerId,IsActive from user where Id in :mgrIds and isactive=true]);
        map<id,List<opportunity>> usrOppMap = new Map<id,List<opportunity>>();
        List<Opportunity> finalOptList=new List<Opportunity>();
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        for(opportunity o:[Select Id,OwnerId,StageName from Opportunity where OwnerId in :usrMap.keyset()])
        {
            if(usrOppMap.containskey(o.ownerid))
            {
                List<opportunity> oppList = usrOppMap.get(o.ownerid);
                oppList.add(o);
                usrOppMap.put(o.ownerid,oppList);
            }
            else{
                usrOppMap.put(o.ownerid,new List<Opportunity> { o });
            }
        }          
        for(User u:usrMap.values()){   

            for(Opportunity opt:usrOppMap.get(u.id){
                if(opt.StageName!='Closed Won' && opt.StageName!='Closed Lost')
                {
                    if (managerUsrMap.containskey(u.managerid)) {
                        opt.OwnerId=u.ManagerId;
                    }
                    else{ 
                        opt.OwnerId=usr.Id;
                                   }
                                   finalOptList.add(opt);
                                   // Set list of people who should get the email
                                   List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
                                   sendTo.add(u.ManagerId);
                                   mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
                                   //  Set who the email is sent from
                                   mail.setReplyTo('flow@test.com');
                                   mail.setSenderDisplayName('Support');
                                   // Set email contents - you can use variables!
                                   mail.setSubject('Open Opportunities transferred to you');
                                   String body = 'Dear Manager,<br> ';
                                   body +='<br>';
                                   body += 'Please note that '+u.name+'  has been deactivated as a Salesforce User hence all of its <br> Open Opportunities has been assigned to you if any.<br>';
                                   body +='<br>';
                                   body +='Kind regards,<br>';
                                   body +='<br>';
                                   body +='SFDC Support';
                                   mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                                   isUpdate=true;
                                   msgList.add(mail);
                                   }
                                   }


                                   }


                                       update finalOptList;



                                       Messaging.sendEmail(msgList,false);




}


                                   @InvocableMethod(label='Change Opportunity Owner' description='It Change the owner of opportunity when owner is inactive')
                                   public static void changeOwnerFuture(List<Id> usrIds)
                                   {
                                       changeOwner(usrIds);
                                   }

                                       }
```

Comment: The try-catch isn't necessary, the query could be optimized, and the guards around the DML and sendEmail are no longer necessary.

Comment: @PreyaMihandoss for (User u1 : [SELECT Id, isActive FROM User]) { 
            mapUserToActive.put(u1.Id, u1.isActive);
        }   in this loop I check Manager is active or not.If Manager is Active then I am assigning all opportunities to User's manager.If user does not have manager or manager is blank then I am assigning all open optys to the special business person

Comment: updated as per sfdcfox's comment and op's comment

Comment: Thanks Preya,This is also works..Thank You so much for your help..

Answer (score 0):

You can't send more than 10 emails with the `sendEmail()` method because of governor limits :

```
Total number of sendEmail methods allowed : 10
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

If you want to send more than 10 emails in a process, you need to use batch :

http://forceguru.blogspot.fr/2011/03/how-to-send-more-than-10-e-mails.html

Comment: Indeed! I have already referred the link that you mentioned but having some issue how do i modify it in my existing code.

Comment: You need to use batch if you send more than 10 emails ! You have to rewrite your code, basing on the link I gave you in my answer.

Comment: If You can see the code,I am using future invocable annotation.This method is called from my process builder and the reason that I am using future is because I am doing DML operation on Setup and Non-Setup object.So i am wondering If I use the batch here,will it call from my process builder or not?

Comment: You can use batch in future method !